The EDS file is interpreted differently by the different Studio 5000 versions
Input/Output controller Tags presented by Studio 5000 versions (the same EDS file used):

v33 MINI data as an array:


v34 MINI data as individual items:


v35 MINI data as an array:


v36 MINI data as individual items: (sorry, no screenshot taken)


Plc in the project: 5069-L340ER
My goal is to have the data in an array in each version... probably some changes in the EDS file are necessary but there are no direct indications in EDS how the data should be presented... Maybe some of you faced the same problem?
Rockwell support is not really helpful... they pointed out that some versions do not support UINTS data type, but changing it in the EDS does not help...
I didn't find any relevant information in the release notes from those versions
I discovered a workaround to export the object from v33 and import to v34. With this solution, it is possible to have the data in an array but this approach is not acceptable to me...

Can you post your EDS file here?

downloadable from here:
it's an io-link master
https://fileport.io/hsaN7MUtrGaC
